# Sorting a file list in WIndows

Tags: sorting, filenames, parser

Got a list of color photos from `Hatton1.jpg` to `Hatton72.jpg` each photo has an identical black and white one named `Hatton1-2.jpg` through `Hatton72-2.jpg`

Is there a way to strip out the -2 files to a separate directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `move` command with the appropriate arguments:

> move *-2.jpg c:\somefolder

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, because of short file names:-

- In order to maintain some sort of compatibility with old programs which were able to handle only short file names, Windows provides an alternative 8.3 name for each longer file name.
- The 8.3 names are in the format `*~N.???`, where `*` is the beginning of the file name and `N` is an integer (where there are few clashes) - see `dir /x`.
- Unfortunately, searching for `*~2.*` will find some of these short names as well as the files you want, with `*~2.*` in the long name.

In `cmd`, go to the directory with the files: you can list the ones you want to move with:

```
dir /b | findstr "~2.jpg"
```

Ideally, you should be able to use:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b | findstr "~2.jpg"') do move "%f" NewDirPath
```

Unfortunately again, you can't use a pipe in an embedded command in a `for` loop, so you need to use two commands (or three to remove the temporary file):

```
dir /b > Files.lst
for /f %f in ('findstr "~2.jpg" Files.txt') do move "%f" NewDirPath
del Files.lst
```

It's not a very elegant solution, but you're probably only doing it once. If you need to do it repeatedly, put the commands in a batch file and make sure you double the `%` in the loop variable:

```
...
for /f %%f in ('findstr "~2.jpg" Files.txt') do move "%%f" NewDirPath
...
```

Comment: And what is wrong on move *-2.jpg ? Why is this complicated solution  needed instead?

Comment: @duDE - I thought I made it clear: `move *-2.jpg` is liable to move irrelevant files with matching short names.

Comment: Sorry, AFH, I see it now :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell you can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) together with [`Move-item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-5.1).

It would look something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*-2.jpg' -Recurse | %{Move-Item $_ C:\Target}
```

I didn't test that code but it should be very similar. Using just the regular Windows search and dragging the files would also likely work.